# Items won't show in inventory

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

Every time I break a block I can pick it up but it doesn't show in my Inventory and I really don't like this.

Comment: Are you on a server? Are you on creative?

Comment: Its was made in survival.

Comment: Does the same happen with other worlds?

Comment: Yes this happends in all my worlds

Comment: so it drops, you can see the item. But when you pick it up it's not in your inventory?

Comment: What are you using, iOS or Android?

Comment: You said it was created in survival but check that it still is survival.

Answer (score 2):

Are you in the full version?

The lite version (free) has a few placeholder items, but you can't actually pick anything up.

I'd recommend buying the full version if this is the case.

Are you using the correct tool?

If you try to break a block without using the correct type of pickaxe, it doesn't drop the item you mined.

If this is so, use the correct type of tool.